# Problem with multi item carousel in angular (flickity)

Tags: angular, flickity

I'm trying to use a multi item carousel / content slider in angular. I have an issue with flickity carousel. The items in the carousel align one after the other vertically instead of horizontally. This problem persists with other carousels available on codepen.io as well. Please help.

The carousel shows up this way: [Click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU1Xm.png)

I need it this way:
[Click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAO2x.png)

Comment: Please post the code  or what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

please use ng2-carouselamos it has help you i used it it is working

```
<div ng2-carouselamos [width]="1000 [items]="YourArray" [$item]="itemTemplate" [$prev]="prevTemplate"[$next]="nextTemplate"></div>

        <ng-template #prevTemplate>
          <i class="material-icons slider-arrow-image">navigate_before</i>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template #nextTemplate>
          <i class="material-icons slider-arrow-image">navigate_next</i>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template let-item let-i="index" #itemTemplate>
       // your cords here enjoy
        </ng-template>
```

Comment: please see this answer it is correect